# Sending header parameters in angular2 and reading them from node

Tags: angularjs, node.js, http-headers

In my application I'm trying to send some header parameters from the angular2 application to my node server:

```
var token = localStorage.getItem('token');
var headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
headers.append('Auth-Token', token);

var url = this.baseUrl + '/initdata';

return this._http.get( url, {headers: headers, body : {}}).toPromise()
    .then(response => {
        const status = response.json().status;
        if(status == SERVER_RESPONSE_STATUS.SUCCESS)
        {
            return response.json().result;
        }
        else if( status == SERVER_RESPONSE_STATUS.FAILED)
        {
            throw new Error(response.json().message);
        }
    })
    .catch(this.handleError);
```

}

But the problem is when I'm trying to read the value from node, the value for "auth-token" cannot be extracted (saying undefined)

```
    router.use('/', function (req, res, next) {

        tokenGenerator.verify(req.header('auth-token'), Constants.AUTH_PRIVATE_KEY, function (err, decoded) {

    });
});
```

in angular2, I'm importing Headers from http as well:

```
import {Http, Headers} from "@angular/http";
```

Can someone please help me what's the issue here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can read tokens from header like this

```
if(req.headers.hasOwnProperty('token')) {        
     req.headers.authorization = 'Bearer ' + req.headers.token;        
     token = req.headers.token;      
}
```

To send the token from Ng2

```
headers.append('token', token);
```

This us how I do it.